# Как сделать анимацию SVG текста вокруг многоугольника

Tags: css, анимация, svg

Допустим необходимо равномерно разместить текст вокруг многоугольника, таким образом, чтобы вне зависимости от  длины слов и их количества, а также  размера шрифта,- вся фраза размещалась вдоль сторон многоугольника без перекрытия символов.

Конечно такие условия невозможно выполнить при большом количестве слов и размере шрифта, но в определенных рамках это возможно?

Например, чтобы такие разные фразы, как:

1. Текст шестиугольника
2. Текст вокруг шестиугольника
3. Весь текст целиком вокруг шестиугольника

Одинаково равномерно размещались вокруг сторон шестиугольника без перекрытия начала и конца фразы.

Далее, необходимо сделать анимацию текста вокруг шестиугольника.

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
width="400" height="450">

<polygon id="pol1"  stroke="blue" stroke-width="1" fill="#507676" 
            points="200,75  308,137.5 308,262.5
                    200,325 92,262.5 92,137.5" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 6):

Чтобы разместить текст целиком вокруг фигуры необходимо узнать длину пути, то есть длину периметра сторон многоугольника.
Для нашего примера длина периметра многоугольника будет равна `760px`
Чтобы конец текстовой фразы не перекрывал символы начала и был гарантированный промежуток между ними,- установим `textLength="700"`

Теперь для текста применим атрибут `lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs"`, который выполняет согласование между установленной длиной `textLength="700"` и расчетной длиной текстовой фразы, которая может иметь различные длины в зависимости от количества слов и размера шрифта.

Другими словами она уплотняет текстовую фразу до заданных размеров `textLength="700"` за счет уменьшения ширины отдельных символов

```
<text id="txt1" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="700" font-size="20">
```

Анимация текста вдоль сторон многоугольника достигается изменением атрибута  `attributeName="startOffset"`

**Ниже пример, который работает и в Chrome, FireFox, Opera, IE11 (кроме анимации)**
Начало анимации - клик на кнопке "Старт"

```html
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head> 
<svg id="svg1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 400 450">
<defs>
 <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <stop stop-color="#406666" offset="0%"/>
      <stop stop-color="#fcfcfc" offset="50%"/>
      <stop stop-color="#507676" offset="100%"/>
      <animate attributeName="x2" begin="svg1.click" dur="10s" values="0;0.25;0.5;0.75;1" repeatCount="1"/>
    </linearGradient>
<path id="path1" d="M92 262.5L92,137.5 200,75 308,137.5 308,262.5
                    200,325 92,262.5 92,137.5 200,75 308,137.5 308,262.5 200,325 92,262.5" fill="none" stroke="none"/>
   </defs>
<rect x='0' y='0' width='400' height='450' fill='#DDDDDD' stroke='black'/>
<rect x="1" y="1" width="398" height="378"
        fill="white" stroke="#507676" stroke-width="1" />
<polygon id="pol1" fill="url(#grad1)" stroke="#507676" stroke-width="1" 
            points="200,75  308,137.5 308,262.5
                    200,325 92,262.5 92,137.5" />
<text id="txt1" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="700" font-size="24">
<textPath id="result" method="align" spacing="auto" startOffset="1%" xlink:href="#path1">
<tspan dy="-10"> Весь очень длинный текст целиком вокруг шестиугольника</tspan>
<animate begin="svg1.click" dur="10s" repeatCount="1" attributeName="startOffset" values="4%;54%"/> 
</textPath>
</text>
<g id="start">
<rect  x="285" y="387" rx="10" width="90" height="35" style="fill:#507676;"/>
<text x='300' y='412' fill="white" font-size="25">Старт</text> 
</g>
  <path id="path2" transform="scale(1.25) translate(-40 -40)" d="M92 262.5L92,137.5 200,75 308,137.5 308,262.5
                    200,325 92,262.5 92,137.5 200,75 308,137.5 308,262.5 200,325 92,262.5" fill="none" stroke="#507676" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1"/>  
   <text x="150" y="200" font-size="24px" fill="green">Click me </text>                
</svg>
</html>
```